# UIWebView - Can't Scroll Horizontally 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, scroll

Hi when I load a certain webpage in a `UIWebView`, for some odd reason, it does not allow me to scroll horizontally, only vertically. Other websites that I load into the `UIWebView` allow me to scroll fine horizontally and vertically.

This specific webpage scrolls fine when I visit the webpage in mobile safari but not when I load it in `UIWebView`.

I was able to successfully change the user agent of the `UIWebView` to that of "Mozilla/5.0" and still it did not let me scroll horizontally.

What is the problem and how can I fix/bypass this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** Nevermind, fixed it by setting the `UIWebView` to "Scale Page to Fit" in the `UIWebView` attributes within the interface builder.